# VB.Net DateTime class '#' Symbol

Tags: vb.net, datetime, symbols

Recently I've been doing quite the project mostly working with the DateTime class.

Now,.. I've found a snip of code on the internet as follows:

Const _dt7am As DateTime = #7:00:00 AM#

and I'm just curious to ask what does the # sign do in this syntax?

typing in '#' on Google just brings up everyone's asking's about Preprocessor statements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#` delimits a date, much like `"` delimits a string. Just typing:

```
Const _dt7am As DateTime = 7:00:00 AM
```

won't work, of course. `#` is just what you wrap your date literals with in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

This is the symbol used to denote a `DateTime constant`.  For details, see [Constants and Literal Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dzy06xhf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

This is just like using `!` to denote single precision floats, ie:

```
Const number As Single = 45.23!
```

Answer (score 1):

The #date# is simply compiler-specific syntax to let the compiler know that it's about to read DateTime data.

You can read more about this at the [DateTime MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) (scroll down to "Instantiating a DateTime Object").